# bubble of selected item while searching in UISearchBar like in mail app

Tags: iphone, email, selection, uisearchbar

I would like to implement something close to what happen in mail app in iphone when you enter new address in "To:" field: when you start searching a list of matching addresses appear (this I know how to do) and when you select one then a bubble with the address appears and you can go on adding addresses (this I don't know hot to do).

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the implementation of `TTMessageController` in Joe Hewitt's [Three20 project](http://github.com/facebook/three20). I believe it does something similar.